# Receipt of notification of the arrival of new data from API

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have data on from the api on my app

I am sending the new data from my site

I want to put a message or notification on the application about the arrival of new data for this API

What is the best way to do this task?

This is the data I got

```
struct VideoView_Msrhiat: View {

@StateObject var model = Api()

var body: some View {
    
    
    VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(model.models) { item in

VStack {
                                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        model.getData(url: APIgetURL.Tap1)
    }
}
}
```

Also

```
struct model : Identifiable, Codable {

let id = UUID()
var color : String?
var details : String
}

class Api : ObservableObject{

@Published var models : [model] = []

func getData (url : String) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let token = "38|Xxxx"
    
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models = dataModel                    
            
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }
    }
resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the app to show a notification in the notification center, it's better to use push notifications. If you're not talking about the notification center notifications, it's better to provide more details like how you want this notification to look like and where it should appear.

Comment: The point is that I will make the user send a message to customer support via the api

Comment: And I want to monitor the api if I receive a new message, I receive a message on my application

Comment: You'll really be better off with push notifications in this scenario. Polling the API while the app is running is almost always a suboptimal solution because you drain user's battery, their mobile data and you flood you API with unnecessary requests. Instead, look into push notifications. Have your API call the APNS once the new data is availabled with a relevant payload, then Apple will deliver this payload to the device as a push notification. The notification can be either silent or visible in the notification center.